# Monitoring end of several logs for certain pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I have a list of log files stored in .txt file(each line contains absolute path to one file). What I wanna do is check last 100 lines of each of these logs for two different string patterns and if it does not include either of those then send email warning with this specific file in subject.

```
file="/path/to/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
if tail -n 100 "$line" | grep -qv "[firstLogPattern:bla]"\|"[second.pattern:1234]"; then
    mailx -s "Pattern messages not present in file $line" myemail@domain.com
fi
done < $file
```

Thing is that this piece of code always sends me whole file with list of logs content instead of just specific files that are not logging given strings.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you certain on those square brackets in grep search?

Comment: Those square brackets are part of string I am searching for. It has this pattern [abc.def.ghf:1234]

Comment: Then you should probably escape them ... as it stands you're defining character classes ...

Comment: Well I tried if tail -n 100 "$line" | grep -qv "abc.def.ghi:1234"; then
and the result is still same. It emails me whole content of list file including those that 100% contain the searched pattern.

Comment: There are special characters in regex (`[\^$.|?*+()`). You can't just willy-nilly use those without escaping. Try `grep -qv "\[firstLogPattern:bla\]|\[second\.pattern:1234]\"`

Comment: Does not seem to be the problem. I tried grep -qv "specificstringforonefile" with string containing no special characters and it still emailed me list of all files